# CSS files not updating on Heroku

Tags: python, css, django, git, heroku

Hi, I am running a Django webapp on a Heroku dyno. My problem is the following one: Sometimes, CSS files are not updated after deploy. They are updated on the GitHub repo, but not in the server. I have manually checked them using:heroku run bash -a myapp**, and the code is different from GitHub (I am sure that I checked the deployed branch), they remain in older versions.

Static files are served correctly, I do not get any 404 and it only happens with CSS files. I have tried `heroku restart -a myapp`, but it does not work. If I rename the files, the problem is solved, but as you can imagine this is not a viable solution.

I use the GitHub deploy method, so I do the add, commit, push cycle and then I manually select and deploy the branch from the Heroku dashboard. Does anyone know how can I solve this without changing files' names? Thanks!

My static configuration

```py
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
]
```

This is a piece of one css file, extracted from running:

```sh
heroku run bash
cd static/css/style.css
cat style.css
```

[Server file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uAwyg.png)

And here is an image from the same code fragment from github (same branch as deployed one, of course):
[GitHub file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/01lGH.png)

As you can see they are different, and i have no clue on how to solve it.

Comment: Have you tried `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic`?

Comment: Yes i have tried it, thanks